# Add a string following the value in a JSpinner

Tags: java, swing, jspinner

Is it possible to add a character or a String after the value in a `JSpinner` (something like "xxx€", "xxx months", xxx being the value) ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check out the section from the Swing tutorial on [Specifiying Spinner Formatting](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/spinner.html#format).

The default editor of the spinner is a `JFormattedTextField`. So you can access this and set your own formatting.

If you have never used a JFormattedTextField before then the tutorial also has a section on `How to Use Formatted Text Fields` to help you in creating the mask you want to use.